# AdMob Rewarded Video not showing ads

Tags: admob

I am trying to show rewarded video ads using AdMob. I have added 2 ad networks (AdColony, InMobi) and supplied all required details like account id and so on.

I have also downloaded and compiled network SDKs and Adapters required.

Ad code:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdColonyAdapter.class, AdColonyBundleBuilder.build())
            .build();

videoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(context);
videoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
videoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-*****************", adRequest);
```

The problem is i always get the same response from AdMob:

> There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0

Any ideas how to solve this?

**UPDATE:**

I overcame the issue of loading ads with deleting "addTestDevice()" from the AdRequest. But unfortunately, when i want to "show()" the ads after they are loaded, i get the following errors:

```
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.mediation.client.g.f(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:615)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.b.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:1298)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.client.e.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:65)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.client.zzb$zza$zza.show(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.client.zzi.show(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

`AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
.addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdColonyAdapter.class, AdColonyBundleBuilder.build())
.addNetworkExtrasBundle( AdMobAdapter.class, extras).build();`

Surely inmobi will works. But for me also adcolony has no fill.. unity ads inmobi are working perfectly with this request

Dont forget to add inmobi sdk, inmobilibadapter.jar, unityadadapter and adcolony.jar in your project. You can download it all from admob mediation networks page

Comment: what is extras the second parameter for last call?